# SAP HANA delete all repository objects

Tags: repository, hana

We have a SAP HANA plattform using for test and development.

On this plattform we want do delete all repository objects.

How to do it?

So far we struggle a lot with the issue that we are unable to delete objects since they are used by another object.

(There are many solutions about how to delete a package. But we want to delete everything so that the repository is completely empty)

Answer (score 1):

SAP HANA with enabled repositories (SAP HANA 1 and SAP HANA 2 with XSC enabled) come with required pre-loaded contents. This contents can not/should not be deleted as it is required for the proper functioning of the system.

Aside from deleting specific packages, there is no "reset"-function that would create an empty repository. 
If having a specified initial state for test/dev is absolutely required, I would recommend looking into taking a snapshot of the whole system when no additional packages have been created/imported and restore this snapshot whenever the initial state is required again.